Create colored MacOS button with SwiftUI with the same style as in built-in apps
I have to create a MacOS app with SwiftUI that must look like a built-in app, conforming to all appearance settings.
I need to create accent colored buttons that look like the "Done" button here (Safari - Settings - Search - Manage Websites...)

The best I could get in my app looks like this:

The code I have:
Button (action: {
}, label: {
    Text("Next")
        .padding(EdgeInsets (top: 5, leading: 12, bottom: 7, trailing: 12))
})
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
.foregroundStyle(.white)
.background(Color.accentColor, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0))

/*EDIT: Result with suggestion in comments
Button (action: {
}, label: {
    Text("Next")
        .padding(EdgeInsets (top: 5, leading: 12, bottom: 7, trailing: 12))
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
})
.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)


*/
Is there a builtin style or modifier I am missing?
Thanks for any tips!

buttonStyle has bordered and borderedProminent

With borderedProminent I cannot change the text color and the button color is not perfect either. There even seems to be a gradient on the desired button based on color picking. .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) is better but still not correct.

Remove the .background modifier, and move the foregroundStyle to the button label.

Accent color in OS is set to yellow which still looks different Apple's apps than in mine.

foregroundStyle will change the color of the font with borderedProminent. You can always make your own style too.

That is a .bordered button with the .defaultAction keyboard shortcut. That is, it can be triggered by pressing the return key.
Relevant quote from the documentation:

On macOS, the default button is designated with special coloration. If more than one control is assigned this shortcut, only the first one is emphasized.

Here is some example code that produces such a button:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            
        } label: {
            Text("Done")
        }
        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
    }
}

With the system accent color set to yellow, it looks like this:


This looks absolutely correct. Thank you!

It's all about subtleties. This probably comes close:

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Button("Done") {
                //action here...
            }
            .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
            .shadow(radius: 3, y: 2)
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
    }
}

struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        let color = Color.blue
        configuration.label
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            .padding(.bottom, 3)
            .foregroundStyle(.white.opacity(0.95))
            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.3), radius: 10, x: -10, y: 0)
            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.3), radius: 10, x: 10, y: 0)
            .font(.system(size: 14))
            .fontDesign(.rounded)
            .background {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .fill(color)
                    .stroke(color.opacity(1), lineWidth: 1)
            }
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 1 : 0.95)
            .animation(.interactiveSpring, value: configuration.isPressed)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

You can play around with the stroke opacity and lineWidth, and maybe the shadow opacity, depending on how obsessive you want to get ;).
